# Plot shapes for higher highs from a given starting point (ie, lowest in 50)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

EDIT: Updated this question to use just candles, as adding another condition made it less broadly applicable.

I am trying to plot a shape **every time a `close` is higher than the previous highest `high` point**, starting from a point of reference - that is, a recent low (eg, lowest in 50 bars).

... In other words, after a recent low point in price is reached, plot a shape every time a `close` is higher than the previous `high`.

Here is my current script:

```
//@version=4
study("Counting Higher/Lower Candles v2",overlay=true)

myLow = lowest(low,50)
newHigh = close>=highest(high,barssince(myLow))
plotshape(newHigh)
```

Currently I am getting this study error:

**Study error: Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the 'highest' function. It must be > 0**

I tried changing my line to:

```
newHigh = barssince(myLow)>0 ? close>=highest(high,barssince(myLow)) : na
```

But not only did that not produce any shapes, it also gave me this message in the pine console:

**line 7: The function 'highest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.**

Comment: Most of the highs between your reference point arrow and your first "higher high" arrow are also higher highs. How would you differentiate between the high drawn at your 2nd arrow, and the highs that preceded that 2nd arrow? What makes this 2nd arrow unique?

Comment: Just rewriting comment to make it more clear: Hi @BjornMistiaen - I'm not sure this answers your questions, but not any candle is a valid new high, only candles that are also upward fractals (indicated by olive triangles). So each white arrow points to a new highest fractal (ie, since the recent low price). If I'm not catching your meaning please let me know, thanks. =)

Comment: I updated the question to be more broadly applicable, I can see how including the reference to fractals was making it more abstract than it needed to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See inline comments in code for explanation

```
//@version=4
study("Counting Higher/Lower Candles v2",overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)

var float   ll      = na
var float   cll     = na
var int     bsll    = na
var int     bsll1   = na
var float   hi      = na
var bool    newHigh = na

ll      := lowest(low,50)
cll     := change(ll)
bsll    := barssince(cll)   // Minimum is zero, so not usable with highest() which has min length of 1
bsll1   := nz(bsll) + 1     // Add 1 to use with highest()
hi      := highest(bsll1)

newHigh := close >= hi[1]   // We cannot use the most recent bar, because when it's the highest high, it's close will likely be lower.

// All in one:
// newHigh = close >= highest(nz(barssince(change(lowest(low,50))))+1)[1]

plotshape(newHigh, "newHigh", style=shape.cross, color=color.yellow)
```

Update 1 (11 Dec 2020)

```
//@version=4
study("Counting Higher/Lower Candles v2",overlay=true)

myLow   = lowest(low,50)
newHigh = close >= highest(high, max(1, nz(barssince(myLow))) )

plotshape(newHigh, color=color.yellow)
```

Update 2 (11 Dec 2020)

```
//@version=4
study("Counting Higher/Lower Candles v2", overlay=true)

hh = close > highest(int(abs(nz(lowestbars(low,50)))) + 1)[1]

// This will work too, and elimiates the need for the int() and abs() function calls
// hh = close > highest(-nz(lowestbars(low,50))+1)[1]

plotshape(hh, color=color.yellow)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Bjorn! It seems to be giving false signals - see this image: https://ibb.co/M25s8kN (several examples shown). You can see lower highs being painted without there being a new lowest in 50 bars - they should only ascend unless there is a new lowest in 50 present.

Comment: I've made a new attempt. See my updated answer. How's this?

Comment: Hi @Bjorn Mistiaen - thanks. You can see there are still some issues after adding this to a chart and checking. I've identified two issues on this screen capture: https://ibb.co/2yfYHQ8 , namely 1) The script fails to indicate certain higher closes as shown in the red oval. 2) The script indicates certain "lower highs" as shown in the purple oval. I am not aware of any other issues, but those jumped out.

Comment: I think I have the correct solution now. See `Update 2 (11 Dec 2020)` in my answer. This would work too `hh = close > highest(-nz(lowestbars(low,50))+1)[1]` and eliminates the need for the `int()` and `abs()` function calls.

Comment: Gah, hate to say it but still seeing lower highs being plotted... Eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9riJ.png - I guess I found a good question!

Comment: The reference point is the lowest low of the last 50 bars. That is where your measurement in your picture ends. So that's the newest reference point. So the marked high is valid.